# Adding a shell command inside/inline of a systemd service file

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

I am running the `gunicorn` server as a service via systemd, Here is the sample `service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn NGINX
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/test
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 8 --threads 8 --backlog 100 --bind 10.0.0.20:5000 -m 777 abc:app
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want now to replace the number near `--workers` and `--threads` by number of cores using the shell command so that it will dynamically pick the number of cores

```
nproc --all
```

Can someone help me how to do this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can explicitly invoke a shell to get shell parsing.

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers "$(nproc --all)" --threads "$(nproc --all)" --backlog 100 --bind 10.0.0.20:5000 -m 777 abc:app'
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but can you tell me how to do `--threads "$(nproc --all)" * 4`

Comment: @Venkata S S K M Chaitanya A bit complicated one (if needed):
--threads "$((($(nproc --all) * 2) + 1))"